# Setting up postgresql in Travis CI for django project

Tags: python, django, postgresql, travis-ci

I am trying to setup continuous integration for my django project. Since I am using postgresql als my database, I want to setup the same in travis. This is my travis.yml file:

```
language: python
services:
- postgresql
python:
- 3.4
env:
- DJANGO=1.8 DB=postgres
before_install:
- export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=ledenbestand.settings.local
install:
- pip install -r travis/requirements.txt
before_script:
- psql -c 'create database ledenbestand;' -U postgres
script:
- python manage.py test
notifications:
  email:
    recipients:
      - random@email.com
    on_success: never
    on_failure: always
```

The problem is that this will fail because my local.py settings also gives a password when connecting to the database, the postgres user on travis doesn't have a password:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'ledenbestand',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        **'PASSWORD': 'password',**
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

The travis documentation says the following:

*Should your local test setup use different credentials or settings to access the local test database, we recommend putting these settings in a database.yml.travis in your repository and copying that over as part of your build:*

```
before_script:
  - cp config/database.yml.travis config/database.yml
```

I however have no clue how this could work, how can this line of code overwrite my local.py settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this by adding an If statement in my config file:

```
if 'TRAVIS' in os.environ:`
```